# Are there other patches available for purchase other than those Logic Pro X ships with?

Tags: logic-pro

There are many places one can get patches for 3rd party plugins like Massive.

The value I see in this is that patches are neatly organised according to genre, genres Logic's patches may just miss if there are pretty specific sounds I'm after.

I was wondering if it's possible to purchase patch packs for Logic Pro X that are neatly organised by type.

I tried Googling, but it just brought up illegal download patch results.

Comment: Do you want more synthesizers, or configurations for Logic's built-in synthesizers?

Comment: More patch configurations (that include Smart button presets)